# Loop cut: wheel not working as expected

Tags: modeling

I'm using Blender 3.0 on Windows 10 Pro, and I just noticed that if I call the loop cut tool from the keyboard shortcut (CTRL-R), then the mouse wheel adjusts the number of cuts as expected.

On the other hand, if I call that tool from the side toolbar, then the wheel zooms in-out and has no effect on the number of cuts.

Is that the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Number of cuts is set from tool settings:

[image]

Comment: Sure, but what I'm trying to figure out is if the different behaviors are by design, or if it could be a setting on my side.

Comment: It is a design. How is it expected to zoom in and out when the tool is selected?

Comment: The same as when we call the tool with CTRL-R?

Comment: When you press some operator like Ctrl+R, in goes to "modal" mode. You are not able to manipulate the view while it is active. Not only scroll but even rotate (except knife tool and some others) It allows us using all hotkeys, that usually manipulate the view. But using tools doesn't lock the view, so this hotkeys can't be used.

Comment: I see. Is this way of doing things pretty consistent in Blender, or is it only a handful of tools that behave like this? I think it would be nice for the documentation team to add such a note. I will enter a "ticket" on their system. I needed to validate first if I was not either doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, it's not a bug actually, because it works as expected. You can make a post at devtalk.blender.org though. And I don't see a lack in documentation, it has a section about tool settings: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html#tool-settings

Comment: When I mention creating a ticket, it's not to report a bug in the software, but rather a lack of clarity in the documentation. After reading the two different versions of the tool, `Loop-Cut` and `Loop-Cut and slide`, I now see that both are indeed documented, but for newcomers like myself, a bit more clarity wouldn't hurt.